# How can I get the dataurl for a remote image without CORS headers?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to grab the raw dataurl for any externally hosted image but am experiencing cors issues.

Adding this did not solve my problem:

> img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image:

> Although you can use images without CORS approval in your canvas, doing so taints the canvas. Once a canvas has been tainted, you can no longer pull data back out of the canvas. For example, you can no longer use the canvas toBlob(), toDataURL(), or getImageData() methods; doing so will throw a security error.

Using the fetch api produced the same errors.

Are there any other ways besides using a proxy that I may request the image data?

Comment: If you're not in control of the servers hosting the external images, no there is not.

Comment: @Kaiido The two possible options that would try would be to use a browser extension or `ServiceWorker` to intercept response body of request for image; or take screenshot of rendered `<img>` element at `html`. Though you would be far more aware of the possibilities of within this topic than here. The former would probably be option that OP is looking for, as previous Question asked specifically about `MIME` type of original image; latter approach would not necessarily maintain same `MIME` type of original image.